# How to create progress bar from the start of Execwait function till the end of Execwait in NSIS?

Tags: windows, installation, nsis, progress

How to create progress bar from the start of Execwait function till the end of Execwait in NSIS?

I have a custom page, In the leave function of custom page I am calling some other function and then I call uninstaller to install the previous version. I would like to display progress bar or any other UI just to convey to the user tat un-installation is going on. After this uninstallation installation of the current version will be called.

Any help is highly appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

If you are executing a MSI then there is an [API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa370573) so you can monitor the progress. NSIS does not have native support for this though...

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to Monitor the `ExecWait` progression.

I you can modify the uninstaller that is started via `ExecWait`, try to show a progression in that part.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Marquee plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Marquee_plug-in) to show a scrolling text during the `ExecWait` call:

```
Marquee::start /NOUNLOAD /color=0x000000 /top=80 "Running $PROGRAM"
ExecWait "$PROGRAM"
Marquee::stop
```